# What is the right way to work with large external hard drives?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, gparted, ext4

I own [this](http://www.amazon.ca/Seagate-Expansion-Desktop-External-STEB5000100/dp/B00TKFEEBW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1444308718&sr=8-1&keywords=5tb%20external%20hard%20drive) external HD.

When I `sudo fdisk -l`

I'm given this output:

```
zach@tux:~/code/bing$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 251.0 GB, 251000193024 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30515 cylinders, total 490234752 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1      409639      204819+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2   *      409640    96523335    48056848   af  HFS / HFS+
/dev/sda3        96523336    97792871      634768   af  HFS / HFS+
/dev/sda4        97794048   490233855   196219904   83  Linux

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 5001.0 GB, 5000981077504 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 608001 cylinders, total 9767541167 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x105c1e3d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1          33          16+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdb2              34      262177      131072   da  Non-FS data
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdb3   *      266240  1177604095   588668928   da  Non-FS data
```

I had originally installed `ntfs` as the file system, but it started failing after a million or so files. I lost everything on the drive after restarting my computer. I then switched to `ext4` but after (what I thought was) safely rebooting I added a file to the hard drive via `sudo mv file /mount/my_disk` which is where I had set it up. I then went to check to see if another file was on that disk and the only thing present on the disk was the file I moved onto it. Ie, I lost the file again. I then checked with parted to see if the disk is ok but I got this message:

```
Error: File system has an incompatible feature enabled.
Compatible features are has_journal, dir_index, filetype, sparse_super and
large_file.
Use tune2fs or debugfs to remove features.
```

Setting up `ext4` was incredibly difficult with parted because parted didn't support `ext4` so I had to use a combination of parted and other tools.

I just want a fast 5TB external hard drive that can handle lots of small files. What should I do? Are there any HDs that don't have GPT that I can buy and just use normal tools to set this up? Why is everything still so difficult? I understand I'm currently frustrated at losing my files (again), but this is getting ridiculous.

Comment: have u tried gparted GUI?

Comment: @AizuddinZali I have not since I normally just SSH into the box from my laptop, but thanks for the idea, I'll try it when I get home.